How to attach Phone Number to Twilio Messaging Service "IS.." Sid via API
I'm trying to create a Twilio messaging service via api as documented here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/api/service-resource#request-body-parameters
and add a phone number to it as described here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/api/phonenumber-resource#create-a-phonenumber-resource-add-a-phone-number-to-a-messaging-service.
When implemented using javascript/bash(?) it returns a messaging service starting with "MG..."
createMessagingService() {
  MESSAGINGSERVICE=$(curl --location "https://messaging.twilio.com/v1/Services" \
--user "${subSid}:${subAuth}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data-urlencode "FriendlyName=${messagingServiceName}")
  messagingServiceSid=$(jq -r '.sid' <<< "${MESSAGINGSERVICE}")
  echo $MESSAGINGSERVICE
}

But when I implement it using java it returns a messaging service starting with "IS..."
public Service createMessagingService(String name) {
        Twilio.init(subAccount.getSid(), subAccount.getAuthToken());
        Service service = Service.creator(name).create();
        return service;
}

This is a problem because when trying to add a phone number to a messaging service it isn't recognizing the "IS.." sid. It only only works for a "MG..." sid.
2024-07-31 16:19:15 SEVERE: Unexpected error occurred: The requested resource /Services/IS.../PhoneNumbers was not found
PhoneNumber phoneNumber = PhoneNumber
                    .creator(messagingService.getSid(), phoneNumberSid)
                    .create();


Twilio Evangelist here,
The "ISxxxxxx" Service SID refers to a Conversation Service instance which is created using the following resource: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/service-resource#create-a-service.
The Messaging Service "MGxxxx" is created using the same code: https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/api/service-resource, but the imported service is different.
Here you can find an example in Java to create the resource, both services are commented, and each import should return a different SID:
import com.twilio.Twilio;

// Messaging Service(MGxxxxxxxx)  
// import com.twilio.rest.messaging.v1.Service;

// Conversations Service (ISxxxxxx)
// import com.twilio.rest.conversations.v1.Service;

public class Example {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Service service = Service.creator("FriendlyName").create();

        System.out.println(service.getSid());
    }
}

In order to properly create a Messaging Service using Java, make sure to import and call the right service:
import com.twilio.rest.messaging.v1.Service;.

Thank you so much! That really clears things up, I was using the wrong import: com.twilio.rest.chat.v1.Service.
